# Google Playstore: Upload Different versions?

Tags: android, google-play

is there any possibility to upload different Versions of the same App to the Playstore?

Thanks,
VanDahlen

Comment: nope, only one version for both smartphones and tablets

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

No, the package name of your app will be the same, Playstore can have only one app with the same package name. Even if your version will be different the package name will be same.

Answer (score 0):

Play store have only one package name regarding to the app,we can upload new .apk file as a new version like 1.1.1(version) with some description.That version we can change in AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, You can upload different version of the same App to the Playstore.
Just Goto AndroidManifest -> change android:versionCode="*" 
(i.e. increase the versionCode value by 1).

Every time when you upload the same app on playstore. You have to change the versioncode.

It is upto you, you want to change your versionName or not.